# How to find the URL that served the flutter web application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'd my webapp to available at:

```
  http://example.com/ui/      # My flutter web application
  http://example.com/api/...  # REST endpoints
```

How can I find the URL from which my app was downloaded (`http://example.com/ui/`), so that can produce the URL `http://example.com/api/` from it?

I'd prefer to not bake the `example.com` into the webapp because we deploy to a number of clusters with difference domain names during CI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

...
debugPrint('host=${html.window.location.host + html.window.location.pathname}');
...
```